# cpanelresult: { apiversion: '2', error: 'Access denied', data: { reason: 'Access denied', result: '0' }, type: 'text' }

Tags: javascript, subdomain, cpanel

I am working on a new project whereby after a user signup they will be asked to enter a name they can use as the subdomain e.g name.example.com so i tried creating a backend that i can send request to for creating the subdomain through cpanel api but its not working

I keep getting this error

```
  cpanelresult: {
    apiversion: '2',
    error: 'Access denied',
    data: { reason: 'Access denied', result: '0' },
    type: 'text'
  }
```

Ive checked everything in my backend code but it's not creating the subdomain

The code below  is the javascript code i tried

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function createSubdomain() {
  try {
    // Replace these values with your cPanel credentials and domain information
    const cpanelUsername = '***********';
    const cpanelApiToken = '****************';
    const cpanelServer = 'example.nameserver';
    const domain = 'example.com';
    const subdomain = 'newsub';

    // Construct the cPanel API URL
    const apiUrl = `https://${cpanelServer}:2083/json-api/cpanel`;

    // Construct the API request payload
    const requestData = {
      cpanel_jsonapi_user: cpanelUsername,
      cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion: 2,
      cpanel_jsonapi_module: 'SubDomain',
      cpanel_jsonapi_func: 'addsubdomain',
      domain: subdomain,
      rootdomain: domain,
      dir: `/${subdomain}`
    };

    // Make the API request using axios and await for the response
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, requestData, {
      auth: {
        username: cpanelUsername,
        password: cpanelApiToken
      }
    });

    console.log('Subdomain created successfully:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating subdomain:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
  }
}

// Call the async function
createSubdomain();
```

But it didnt work i keep getting errors and cpanel documetation is not really good for this.
Cpanel documentation only works with session Id in thhe currrent browser that i used in logging in to my cpanel account.

Pls if there is an alternative in doing this i'll be happy to hear it cause i don't have any idea in doing it.